# how to make today's date default value in bootstrap date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap date picker in aspx

```
 <input type ="date" id="todays-date" value="" class="form-control">
```

I am trying to make default value as today's date but from JavaScript

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd ;
$("#todays-date").attr("value", today);
```

This is not working. In developer tools console I can see input tag value as today's date but default value in input form control is still mm/dd/yyy.

[here is the js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ymu177dj/)

Comment: You have to include jQuery for starters: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymu177dj/2/)

Comment: You forgot to include jquery.

Comment: @ikegami: My link says otherwise.

Comment: I have included this in the head Tag  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Bhargavi: Post the content of your `head`

Comment: The script in head gives me 404.

Comment: @Jason Here is my head tag. But, Below answer worked for me. Thank you  <head runat="server"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/site.css" />
<link href="~/content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script> </head>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Made small changes to your existing code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymu177dj/8/)

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = ("0" + (today.getDate())).slice(-2);
var mm = ("0" + (today.getMonth() +　1)).slice(-2);
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd ;
$("#todays-date").attr("value", today);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working fine in chrome, but in IE 11 date input is showing today's date as 2015-01-29. It doesn't even show calendar

Comment: @Bhargavi the date type is not yet supported fully by all browsers. Currently only chrome and opera support calendar, mozilla and ie just shows input. The other problem that you have with date format is because the standard format is yyyy-mm-dd, I think the reason that in chrome the format is different it's because it finds the format of your country and use it as default.